# rewriting urls for simple html pages in asp.net MVC app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, global-asax

I have asp.net mvc application.

And I have html page. called lp.html.

i want to rewrite page name `url` from lp.html to something else, lets say `appndomainname.com/location`

how can I do this, because in this case I am dealing with simple html pages. No controller or controller method.

So code like this won't be needed

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: no, i need app level rewriting